# Переход на Activity после воспроизведения анимации кнопки

Tags: java, android, android-on-click

Код ниже добавляет анимацию Scale для кнопки. Подскажите пожалуйста, как по клику на эту кнопку перейти на другое Activity?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Animation animScale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale);
        Button btnScale1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnScale1.setOnClickListener(view -> view.startAnimation(animScale));
```

Пытаюсь построить логику по совету ЮрийСПб следующим образом:

```
animScale.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animScale) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, p1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Android Studio ругается на строчку: new Animation.AnimationListener()

Полный код:

```
package en.my.voicechat;
 
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
 
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
 
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 
        //задаем анимацию для каждой кнопки
        final Animation animScale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale);
        Button btnScale1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnScale1.setOnClickListener(view -> view.startAnimation(animScale));
 
        Button btnScale2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btnScale2.setOnClickListener(view -> view.startAnimation(animScale));
 
        Button btnScale3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btnScale3.setOnClickListener(view -> view.startAnimation(animScale));
 
        Button btnScale4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        btnScale4.setOnClickListener(view -> view.startAnimation(animScale));
 
        Button btnScale5 = findViewById(R.id.button5);
        btnScale5.setOnClickListener(view -> view.startAnimation(animScale));
 
        Button btnScale6 = findViewById(R.id.button6);
        btnScale6.setOnClickListener(view -> view.startAnimation(animScale));
 
        Button btnScale7 = findViewById(R.id.button7);
        btnScale7.setOnClickListener(view -> view.startAnimation(animScale));
 
        //пытаемся применить для седьмой кнопки переход на Activity
        animScale.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animScale) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, p7.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
 
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам, наверное, надо после окончания анимации? Тогда повесьте на неё слушатель окончания, а в нём - запуск новой активити посредством метода startActivity, куда надо Intent передать, в коем указано какую активити отобразить.

Comment: А зачем добавление анимации сделано по клику?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Можно пример кода? Я только начал изучать Java

Comment: @DrMcSheen наглядная реализация на видео: https://radikal.ru/video/Jy1ZvhoXnqC
При нажатии кнопки проигрывается короткая анимация

Comment: @DrMcSheen Делал по примеру из интернета. Возможно код неправильный

Comment: @AnatolijRojs, а как именно студия ругается? Важно скорее это, а не сам факт ругани) Вам надо или импортнуть что-то или вы не тот слушатель передаёте или надо и остальные методы AnimationListener переопределить. Вроде бы это основные варианты на что может ругаться. Но могу ещё несколько расписать. Надеюсь, это продемонстрирует, что обязательно надо подробно описать что сообщает студия, чтобы сократить список возможных проблем и путей их решения. Иначе - ответ может не то что в ограничение длины коммента поместиться, но даже и ответа.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Implement Methods. Наверное, чтобы разобраться лучше выложить полный код: https://pastebin.com/BpVpRPCK

Comment: Ходить по незнакомым ссылкам я не буду и вам не советую) Если у вас такая ошибка - реализуйте недостающие методы. Самый простой способ - курсор на строку красным подчёркнутую поставить и нажать Alt+Enter и Enter - методы сами появятся

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вставил полный код

Comment: Полный код было не обязательно показывать) Лучше сделайте как я предлагал в последнем предложении комментария выше